# Grunt server local host not responding

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

Just built using

```
yo webapp
```

afterwards tried to preview it, as the website says, with

```
grunt server
```

and I get the error in the browser "No data received"

Any idea what the issue could be here?

The command

```
grunt test
```

works fine, I get back

```
Running "mocha:all" (mocha) task
Testing: http://localhost:9000/index.html

  ․

  1 test complete (109 ms)

>> 1 passed! (0.11s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of livereload (0.2.0) needs to installed.

In the webapp folder use the command

```
npm install connect-livereload
```

and the error is fixed